# onClick works only once

Tags: javascript, html

I input the values, and it works ONCE, which is a problem.
I try to change the numbers, and click Enter again, and it does nothing.
The only way it works again is if I use the scroll to up or down the current value.

```js
var fuel = 2.5;
  var mpg = 6;

  function Hourly() {
    var miles = document.getElementById('miles').value;
    var brokerPay = document.getElementById('pay').value;
    var gallons = miles / 6;
    var hours = miles / 55;
    var cost = gallons * fuel;
    var net = brokerPay - cost
    var hourlyPay = net / hours;
    var newHeader = document.getElementById('changeMe');
    newHeader.innerHTML = hourlyPay;
  }
```

```html
<h1 id="changeMe">Change me Here</h1>
<input type="number" placeholder="miles" id="miles" required/>
<input type="number" placeholder="Broker Pay" id="pay" required/>
<input type="submit" value="Enter" onclick="Hourly()" />
```

Comment: The code works properly for me in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/2142/ . do you have any console errors?

Comment: @born2gamble What do you mean by "only once"?